Polkadot.js never connects to local instance of Chopsticks
I'm trying to test extrinsics on HydraDX chain. Chopsticks UI never returns for the types of errors I'm running into, so I'm trying to use command line. You can run a local fork with Chopsticks and then connect the Polkadot.js UI to that endpoint, but for me it never connects. What's wrong with my call or link?
local call to start Chopsticks:
npx @acala-network/chopsticks@latest --endpoint=wss://rpc.hydradx.cloud -c hydradx
...
[14:43:13.034] INFO: Loading config file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks/master/configs/hydradx.yml
    app: "chopsticks"
[14:43:14.771] INFO: HydraDX RPC listening on port 8000
    app: "chopsticks"

Now I should be able to access that instance at ws://localhost:8000
So I tried to access it in from: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000#/accounts
the website loads, but always displays Waiting to establish a connection with the remote endpoint.
